# Can't get javascript dropdown to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a Javascript menu. The hover and click for the main menu items work however, I cannot get the dropdown to work.

menu.js is

```
 /* When the user clicks on the button,
     toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
 function myFunction() {
   //document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
   //document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content").show);
   //document.getElementById("pmd").classList.toggle("show");
   pmd.show;
 }
 }
 // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
 window.onclick = function(event) {
   if(!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
     var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
     var i;
     for(i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
       var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
       if(openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
         openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
       }
     }
   }
   if(!event.target.matches('.dropbtnpm')) {
     var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
     var i;
     for(i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
       var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
       //if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
       openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
     }
   }
 }
```

My HTML for the menu where I want a dropdown  is as follows. I'm just trying to get it to work with text of 'test'. I can do the link later

```
 <td><button onmouseover="myFunction();"
 onclick="location.href='property-mngt.html';" value="Property Management"
 class="dropbtn">PROPERTY MANAGEMENT</button>
<div id="pmd" class="dropdown-content"> test </div>
 </td>
```

The CSS is

```
.dropbtn {
  border:  none;
  padding: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: black;
  height: 125px;
  min-height: 125px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #004b8d;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  color: #ffff33;
}
.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
.show {
  border: 1px solid #33ccff;
  display: block;
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: #004b8d;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: small;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  color: black;
}
```

My goal is to have the dropdown list appear when hovering over that particular menu item. If I change the html to `<div id="pmd" class="dropdown-content.show"> test </div>` 'test' shows on the menu.

I'm stuck on getting the mouseover of that menu item to show the dropdown.

Comment: The JavaScript code doesn't seem to be complete. What should `pmd.show` do, what is `pmd` and there is at least one curly brace too much.

Comment: Just because I'm curious: why are you using javascript to show a menu? Why not just use CSS and HTML, that way you make sure your menu is available to everyone, even people with both JS and CSS turned off.

Comment: Also why are you using `<button>` and script to do what an `<a href>` is meant for?

Comment: Based on  junkfoodjunkie's comment I changed it over to CSS/HTML. That part is working now. 

gus27 - pmd was for 'property management dropdown'  I was just trying to debug with that. 

charlietfl - I was trying to get a very particular look and feel for the menu and needed large blocks to be clickable. I was trying to do it without creating menu images since there might be changes. 

At any rate, the menu is now working using just CSS/Html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're trying to show multiple elements. take the first and and display it correctly.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-content')[0].style.display = 'block'
```

or use use the `document.querySelector('dropdown-content')`

Comment: I used the second option and it worked. However, based on the comments above, I changed the menu over to CSS/HTML.